# I want to know if the xsd:pattern value is correct

Tags: xml

I want to request data from SAP based on a date in time .
I use a SOAP Message to do that.
In the XML of the SOAP message for the date variable I have this piece of code that was not developed by me .

```
**<xsd:simpleType name="date10">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
<xsd:pattern value="\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>**
```

I am not sure that the way it's written is ok.
It should be a date , not a string.

Please tell me if the way it's written may be correct .
From my point of view it should be xsd:date with the pattern value "\y\y\y\y-\m\m-\d\d".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a reason it was defined as a string with a particular pattern rather than as a date, for example if the schema is used for data binding as well as validation. But you're right, defining it as xs:date would be more natural. Of course the current definition allows things like 2021-02-31 which xs:date would not allow.

Also, `\d` allows digits other than 0-9 (for example Indic digits), which xs:date would not allow.

The type xs:date allows a timezone. You might want to disallow that (which can be done with a pattern).

If you do use xs:date, then you don't need a pattern. The pattern value `"\y\y\y\y-\m\m-\d\d"` is nonsense. But you may want to add a pattern for example to disallow timezones or dates before 0AD.